# Case sensitivity in conditional str_replace_all in r

Tags: r, regex

For example I have this code.

```
# Lookup List
fruits <- c("guava","avocado", "apricots","kiwifruit","banana")
vegies <- c("tomatoes", "asparagus", "peppers", "broccoli", "leafy greens")

# Patterns
foods <- c("guava", "banana", "broccoli")
patterns <- str_c(foods, collapse="|")

# Sample Sentence
sentence <- "I want to eat banana and broccoli!" 


typeOfFood <- function(foods) {

  if( foods %in% fruits ){
    type <- "FRUITS"
  }
  else if( foods %in% vegies ){
    type <- "VEGIES"
  }
  paste0(foods,"(",type,")")

}

str_replace_all(sentence, patterns, typeOfFood)
```

Output:

```
[1] "I want to eat banana(FRUITS) and broccoli(VEGIES)!"
```

**I want to ignore the case sensitivity without using tolower(sentence).**

Sample Sentence:

```
sentence <- "I want to eat BANANA and Broccoli!"
```

Sample Output:

```
[1] "I want to eat BANANA(FRUITS) and Broccoli(VEGIES)!"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `regex()` helper function from `stringr` which has an `ignore_case` option.

You will need to modify `typeOfFood` to ignore case.

```
typeOfFood <- function(foods) {
  if(tolower(foods) %in% fruits ){
    type <- "FRUITS"
  }
  else if(tolower(foods) %in% vegies ){
    type <- "VEGIES"
  }
  paste0(foods,"(",type,")")
}

sentence <- "I want to eat BANANA and Broccoli!"
str_replace_all(sentence, regex(patterns, ignore_case = TRUE), typeOfFood)
# [1] "I want to eat BANANA(FRUITS) and Broccoli(VEGIES)!"
```